# how to convert partial list of columns to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.columns[4:]=pd.to_datetime(df.columns[4:],format='%Y-%m')
```

my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert 5th column to last column using column label to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Because pandas columns names are immutable, you can reassing new values converted to datetimes and lists:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:4].tolist()+pd.to_datetime(df.columns[4:],format='%Y-%m').tolist()
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.set_index(df.columns[:4].tolist())
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns,format='%Y-%m')
```

Comment: it is done. thank you so much.but now, how apply resample only on datetime columns?

Comment: @AniruddhaPal - then is necessary convert first non datetimes columns to `MultiIndex` and then working with datetimes columns - converting and resampling. Answer was edited.